# Unable to create file on Mac in C?

Tags: c, macos

I am trying to create a file in this folder `/Users/xxx/yyy/zzz/priya` on a Mac.

```cpp
FILE *f;
f = fopen("/Users/xxx/yyy/zzz/priya/program.txt", "w");
if (f == NULL) {
  printf("unable to open ");
} else {
  fprintf(f, "log presents ...\n");
}
```

But everytime I get "unable to open". All folders have permission to read and write.But not able to give read and write permission for Macintosh HD. Is this a reason for not creating the file? Any hint will be helpful for me.

Comment: What are the permissions on `/Users/xxx/yyy/zzz/priya` ? Also the path in your program does not match the path in your problem statement ? Can you show the actual output of `ls -l` for whichever directory is correct ? Also are you running the program as user xxx ?

Comment: Is /Users/xxx/yyy/zzz a valid path.. ?

Comment: `fopen` will assign `errno`.  You can inspect it to see why the call failed. eg: `if( (f=fopen(path, mode)) == NULL) { perror(path);}`

Answer (score 0):

A solution is in comments, this is an alternate approach using Mac OSX [mkdir()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdir). It shows how to create each sub-directory in path.

Before calling `fopen()`, parse path into an array of strings,

```
char folder[n][MAX_LEN] = {"Users","xxx","yyy","zzz","priya"}
```

then verify/create each segment exists by walking down all of the component directories:

(Please consider the following pseudo-code, as I posted away from a compiler and it is untested...)

```
struct stat st = {0};
len = strlen("/Users/xxx/yyy/zzz/priya");  //length of original path string  
char newDir[len+1];
int status = -1;
memset(newDir, 0, sizeof(newDir));   
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{ 
    strcat(newDir, "/");
    strcat(newDir, folder[i])
    status = mkdir(newDir, 0700);
    if ((status != 0) && (errno != EEXIST)) 
    {
         //handle error and exit
         break;   
    }
}
```

Comment: A call to `stat` is not necessary. Just go ahead and call `mkdir`. That said, in any case inspect `errno` if `mkdir` failed.

Comment: @user58697 - Good point, edited to just use 'mkdir'